# how can I use pandas assign function with a personal defined function?

Tags: python, pandas, assign

here is my code

```
def calculsComplexesPlusieursColonnes(total_bill,tip,sex):
        if sex=="Female":return total_bill+tip
        else : return total_bill+2*tip

    tips['résultat'] = tips.apply(lambda row: calculsComplexesPlusieursColonnes(row['total_bill'], row['tip'],row['sex']), axis=1)
    tips=tips.assign(résultat_bis=lambda row: calculsComplexesPlusieursColonnes(row.total_bill,row.tip,row.sex))
```

I try 2 ways of creating a new variable using a function : the first one works fine (var résultat) but the second one (var résultat_bis), last line of code doesn't work : I get

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What should I do to make it work?
Yours sincerely Loïc

Comment: please tell me if my solution works

Answer (score 0):

You only need:

```
tips['résultat']=( tips['sex'].ne('Female')
                              .astype(int)
                              .add(1)
                              .mul(tips['tip'])
                              .add(tips['total_bill']) )
```

basically with `Series.ne` + `Series.astype` we create a series with 1 where Sex does not equal Female and 0 where it equals Female. Then we add 1 to this series, then it only remains to multiply and add the corresponding series

I recommend you see:
[`When should I ever want use apply`](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code) and [`Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)